# Theoretical confusion: Contradicting propositions in modular arithmetic?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, modular-arithmetic

Upong reading a discrete mathematics textbook I bought, I encountered firstly the following proposition:

> If $x_0$ is a solution to $xa \equiv b \pmod{m}$, then $x = x_0+km$ defines the set of all possible solutions to  $xa \equiv b \pmod{m}$.

I thought this was reasonable enough. As I went on with the reading, I started to interpret modular arithmetics as the arithmetics of cyclic phenomena. At least that's how I made sense of it.

To be clear about what I mean, I started to read $a \equiv b \pmod{m}$ as "$a$ has the same index than $b$ inside a cycle of $m$ discrete events". For example, $1 \equiv 4 \pmod{3}$ means $1$ and $4$ share an index when we cycle through $\mathbb{Z}$ in cycles of $3$ numbers.

So, it seamed reasonable to say $x = x_0+km$ are the solutions to the equation. $x_0$ solves the equation and $x_0+km$ quite clearly has the same "index" than $x_0$ when we cycle in periods of $m$. Therefore, because $x_0$ has the same "index" than $b$, so does $x_0 +km$ (so transitivtiy also makes sense to me in terms of cycling).

However, further on in the book it reads

> If $\gcd(a, m)=d>1$ and $d|b$ , then $x=x_0+\frac{m}{d}k$ defines the set of all solutions to $xa \equiv b \pmod{m}$.

It goes on to provide a demonstration of this. The demonstration is based on the fact that if $x_1, x_0$ are solutions to the equation, then $a(x_1-x_0) \equiv 0 \pmod{m}$, which is of the form $ay \equiv 0 \pmod {m}$. Equations of this form are solved by the multiples of $\frac{m}{d}$ when $d>1$. The demonstration of this was clear to me.

The book also shows that if $\gcd(a, m)=1$ then $x=x_0+mk$ are solutions, which still is the same as $x=x_0+\frac{m}{d}k$ (for $d=1$).

---

I found both statements quite clear *separately*. However, they seem to contradict each other. The first claims $x=x_0+km$ are the solutions to the linear equation, which seems natural to me in view of my "cyclic interpretation". The second, though, claims $x=x_0+km$ are the solutions only when $d=1$. I have no "intuitive" nor "cyclic" interpretation for the latter, but its formal proof was clear and convincing.

How am I to interpret these propositions? Are they *not* contradictory for some reason I'm missing? I try to develop a real understanding of the math I study, so I really could not let this comprehension issue go.

My guess is there's something I'm missing about the fact that the *second* statement sprouts from the equation $ay \equiv 0 \pmod{m}$ and not the original equation $ax \equiv b \pmod{m}$. However, I haven't been able to clear this in my mind.

For context, I self-study and only started reading modular arithmetics today, so this might be just a silly confusion. Excuse me is that is the case! Thanks.

Comment: You left off necessary assumptions.  For the first, I expect the reference required that $\gcd(a,m)=1$.  The claim is not generally true without that.  For instance, all integers $x$ satisfy $x\times 0 \equiv 0\pmod m$.  The details are critical.

Comment: I can swear such condition for the first statement is not given at the time, nor before the time, such statmenet is provided. Probably just a bad textbook? I was written by a professor at my local university, I pressumed it would be decent.

Comment: I would paste an image of the proposition being given without such condition being made explicit, at the very beginning of the chapter, but it's in Spanish.

Comment: Thank you for the comment by the way.

Comment: As I say, and as the second proposition clarifies, the first claim is generally false without assumptions.

Comment: 1. Some users here can read Spanish, so no reason not to post. 2. We all make mistakes. Finding one in a textbook is a bit of a worry, but not by itself enough to condemn it as a bad textbook.

Comment: Thank you both very much. I'm just happy to see my confusion was justified. With @lulu's clarification I think I can go on with the reading. Thanks!!